# Retrieving a byte array in an UWP AppServiceConnection

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

Continuing from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857804/multiple-partial-results-in-a-uwp-app-service), I am trying to pass data between along `AppServiceConnection`. I am interested in sending and receiving an array of bytes. 
Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367985/how-to-make-a-class-that-can-be-added-to-the-windows-foundation-collections-valu), I know the acceptable types. But the problem is I don't know **how to reproduce the data in the receiving end** and there's no documentation for that.

In particular, I have the following:

```
Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ binaryData;
// ... Omitted code to construct the actual data ...
auto data = ref new ValueSet();
data->Insert("bin", binaryData);
if (_connection != nullptr)
    create_task(_connection->SendMessageAsync(data));
```

in my service code and in my receiver code, I have

```
// Reproduce the data for processing
Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ binaryData = safe_cast<Platform::Array<unsigned char>^>(data->Lookup("bin"));
```

But this crashes the receiver. I try to print out the object `data->Lookup("bin")` and see it's of type `Windows.Foundation.IArrayReference`.

**EDIT**: Silly me, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.IReferenceArray_T_) already tells me that I need to first cast it as `IBoxArray` and get the array via `Value` property:

```
Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ binaryData = safe_cast<Platform::IBoxArray<unsigned char>^>(data->Lookup("bin"))->Value;
```

will do the job.

Comment: Since you already found the answer, please post it as answer and mark the thread as answered, for the benefit of others who find this thread in their search for answers.

Comment: Since you already found the answer, please post it as answer and mark the thread as answered, for the benefit of others who find this thread in their search for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation for IReferenceArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.IReferenceArray_T_) says that one first casts it as `IBoxArray` and get the actual array via `Value` property: Changing to

```
Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ binaryData = safe_cast<Platform::IBoxArray<unsigned char>^>(data->Lookup("bin"))->Value;
```

will do the job.